# Creating a DLL in C++ to import C++ DLL in VS 2005

Tags: c++, dll, dllimport, getprocaddress

I'm trying to link C++ DLL into a new C++ DLL which i will create,

I've followed the below tutorial step by step and many others but something wrong the "GetProcAddress" function returns NULL "http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/118076-dlls-explicit-linking/"

This is the Prototype of the function i try to call from the DLL :

**int RemoveAllDataFile( unsigned int id );**

the function returns with 1 so the DLL is loaded successfully.

```
typedef int (*funcRemoveAllDataFile) (int);

int load_dll_ARbnet(int x)
{
    /* Retrieve DLL handle.*/
    HINSTANCE hDLL = LoadLibrary("ArbNet2Remote.dll");   
    if (hDLL == NULL)
    {
        return 0;
    }    
    else
    {
    }
    /*Get the function address*/
    funcRemoveAllDataFile RemoveAllDataFile = (funcRemoveAllDataFile)GetProcAddress(hDLL, "RemoveAllDataFile");
    if (RemoveAllDataFile)
    {
        return 2;
    }
    else
    {
        return 1;
    }
```

}

Comment: Lookup "C++ name mangling"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the DLL's actual exports, such as with a reporting tool like TDUMP or similar.  The function you are looking for is not being exported as `"RemoveAllDataFile"` like you are expecting.  It is actually being exported like `"_RemoveAllDataFile"` instead, or even something like `"_RemoveAllDataFile@4"`.

If you are compiling the original DLL, and want the function exported as `"RemoveAllDataFile"`, you will have to wrap the declaration of the exported function with `extern "C"` to remove any C++ name mangling from the exported name.  Depending on your C++ compiler, you may also need to use a `.def` file to remove the leading underscore that is imposed by the `__cdecl` calling convention.  When using C linkage, some C++ compilers export `__cdecl` functions with the leading underscore (such as Borland) and some do not (such as Microsoft).

But if you are not recompiling the original DLL, then you have no choice but to look at the DLL's exports and change your `GetProcAddress()` call to use the proper name that is actually being exported.

Comment: works fine now, the dll exported the function as "?RemoveAllDataFile@@YAHI@Z" instead of RemoveAllDataFile. To get the real export i used https://www.virustotal.com , real names are listed under "PE exports" under "file detail" just a quick online solution.

Answer (score 1):

The function you export from the other DLL should be declared `extern "C"` if using C++ source.  If should be exported either with a `.def` file or using `__declspec(dllexport)`:

Here's a typical DLL header file that works with `.c` or `.cpp` and both calling conventions:

```
#ifdef MYAPI_EXPORTS
#define MYAPI __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define MYAPI __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

MYAPI int __cdecl   func1(int x);
MYAPI int __stdcall func2(int x);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

DLL source:

```
#define MYAPI_EXPORTS
#include "x.h"
int func1(int x)
{
    return x*2;
}

int __stdcall func2(int x)
{
    return x*3;
}
```

And usage:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef int (__cdecl   *FUNC1)(int);
typedef int (__stdcall *FUNC2)(int);
int main()
{

    HINSTANCE hDLL = LoadLibrary("x");
    FUNC1 func1 = (FUNC1)GetProcAddress(hDLL, "func1");
#ifdef _WIN64
    FUNC2 func2 = (FUNC2)GetProcAddress(hDLL, "func2");
#else
    FUNC2 func2 = (FUNC2)GetProcAddress(hDLL, "_func2@4");
#endif
    printf("%d %d\n",func1(5),func2(5));
}
```

Name decoration can be discovered with `dumpbin /exports <dll>`.  Note that x64 and x86 differ.  Below is for x86:

```
   ordinal hint RVA      name

         2    0 00001010 _func2@4
         1    1 00001000 func1
```

Comment: `extern "C"` would remove C++ name mangling, but not the leading `_`, you have to use a `.def` file for that.  So you would need to use `extern "C"`, `__declspec(dllexport)`, and `.def` all together in order to export a `__cdecl` function with no decorations of any kind.

Comment: The `__cdecl` calling convention (which this code is using, as it is the default calling convention for most C/C++ compilers, unless configured otherwise) still outputs a leading underscore when `extern "C"` is used by itself (or the source is compiled as C instead of C++).  The .def file is needed to create an exported alias without the underscore.

Comment: Be that as it may, the above code works with `.c` and `.cpp` files on both `x86` and `x64` versions of VS2012.  `dumpbin` shows the undecorated name.  `__stdcall` shows `_funcRemoveAllDataFile@4`.

Comment: I just read the [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zkwh89ks.aspx) for `_cdecl`: "Underscore character (_) is prefixed to names, **except when __cdecl functions that use C linkage are exported.**"  I don't use VC++, and this behavior is different than other C++ compilers that I do use, which do export the underscore on C-linked functions.

Comment: Yes, Microsoft likes to be different :^)  Even if the underscore was left alone it could be used without a `.def` as `GetProcAddress(hDll,"_funcRemoveAllDataFile")`.  The name *does* have a leading underscore as exposed in the `.obj` file.  It's just how Microsoft exports it in the DLL name table.